# Why do my GPU work in the x4 slot. but not in the x16

Tags: motherboard, gpu

I just completed my PC build:
i3-6100 CPU
msi b150 gaming motherboard
XFX Radeon RX480 8Gb
Corsair CX 450M PSU

So I installed the GPU on the first slot, the x16. It didn't work. I get no picture, but when I plug my cable in the integrated graphics, there is picture. The GPU lights up and the fans start spinning, so it's getting power.
Then I tried putting it in the other slot, the x4 one. It works normaly, it gets detected and I can use it that way.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Radeon RX graphics cards are not listed as compatible with the MSI B150 motherboard > https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B150-GAMING-M3.html#support-vga

Comment: Really? Is that the reason?

Comment: Is there a setting in the BIOS for "initial display adapter" or something like that?

Comment: In most cases when you have a fairly new graphics card and the MB vendor does not have it listed as compatible, it'll work but cannot guarantee to work in optimal conditions. That said, MB vendors release BIOS updates to provide support for newer hardware, so i'd suggest you grab the latest bios from MSI released Nov. 3rd 2016 and check again using the 16x slot. > https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B150-GAMING-M3.html#support_download

Comment: there is: Initiate Graphics Adapter. There are 2 options PEG and IGP. It's always set to PEG

Comment: I have the latest BIOS. But it says it's only for newer CPU. 
I noticed they list only MSI GPUs on their website. Does that mean other custom cooler gpus won't work too?

Comment: I have never see a list of "supported" gpus for a motherboard.....

Comment: Another thing you can do is to try another psu. The corsair 450m delivers 450W which may be too low wattage for 16x functionality. As a minimum I'd personally go for a 600w PSU